# add hour-minute to datetime

Tags: php, datetime

can anyone help me in a problem that i am stuck in for long hours, i am trying to add time like in format `h:ia` with hour and minute in format `01:00`(one hour), `00:30`(30 minutes), `02:00`(two hour) etc.. in php.

As i have hours in format like`('00:30','01:00','01:30','02:00')`to the the time i already have.
i tried this

`$interval="01:00";`

`$now=new DateTime('h:ia');`

`$time=($now,strtotime(+$interval,$now));`

but its not working.
 Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should check strtottime() documentation to add 1 hour simply use

```
strtotime("+1 hour");
```

you can also use `time() + 60*60`

There is also method in DateTime object called "[add](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)" that you can use.

From manual:

> DateTime::add -- date_add — Adds an amount of days, months, years, hours, minutes and seconds to a DateTime object

You can create [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object and add the interval to exsiting [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object.

To format date you can use [format()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method on [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object.

**Edited:**

Simple explode may solve your problem as well.

```
 $interval="01:00";
 $xp = explode(":", $interval);
 $time=time() + (int)$xp[0] * 60*60 + (int)$xp[1]*60;
 echo date("h:ia", $time);
```

Or more object oriented soution

```
$interval="01:00";
$now=new DateTime();
$now->add(new DateInterval("P0000-00-00T$interval:00"));
echo $now->format('h:ia');
```

[Working demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/yth-sbr)

Comment: as i already mention i have the format of hour and minute is in `('00:30','01:00','01:30','02:00')`

Comment: but what in case if user selects `00:30` , i dont know what user will select

Comment: it will work also for 00:30 I've simplified it a bit ;) with constructor of DateInterval

Comment: From manual "The format starts with the letter P, for "period." Each duration period is represented by an integer value followed by a period designator. If the duration contains time elements, that portion of the specification is preceded by the letter T."

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like that :

```
$interval = "01:00";
$yourInterval = new DateInterval('P0000-00-00T'.$interval.':00');
//Setting the date and seconds to "0"

$time = new DateTime('now');
//Or any other method to get your DateTime

$time->add($yourInterval);
```

I think that in all cases, you should use DateTime and DateInterval, OR strtotime()
I'm not sure about mixing them.
I prefer to use DateTime and DateInterval because it's more Object oriented.

In all case i advice not to explode for date operation. It's highly dangerous because of many many problems you can't predict (Like bisexstil seconds etc...)

EDIT :
I guess that if you're just manipulating time, and not date, exploding your string is not a problem, the mainly problem is if you use dates.

Comment: yeah i am only manipulating time, add function is not supporting

Comment: because he uses `.` instead of `->` in add method. Check my previous answer and demo.

Comment: Thx Robert ... I got the "Java-addict" sickness !

Comment: what is for `P0000-00-00T`

Comment: @KumariManisha if you'd checked manual and documentation you'd know. Do some research. "The format starts with the letter P, for "period." Each duration period is represented by an integer value followed by a period designator. If the duration contains time elements, that portion of the specification is preceded by the letter T."

Comment: Just as Robert said. So one of string date representation supported  for creating a DateInterval is : 'Pyyyy:mm:ddThh:mm:ss" Because you interval does not use Date and sec, we intialize them with 'P0000-00-00T' and ':00' and concact them with your time string.